# Generate keys for nginx, with only a public key

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I have an Elasticsearch endpoint as a service (I have no access to config/server).  The service provided me with a username and password, and a single "TLS certificate" file, which when decoded says that it is **RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)**

I am running nginx and want to use it as a reverse proxy for this Elasticsearch endpoint.  So I have to get nginx to handle the application of the certificate when it relays the request.  Similar to this example config (from nginx docs):

```
location /upstream {
        proxy_pass                    https://backend.example.com;
        proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/client.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/client.key;
        proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted_ca_cert.crt;
        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
```

Any idea how I can generate the **client.pem** and **client.key** required (e.g. using openssl) -- when all I have to start with is a single public key file?

**(edit)**

Not sure if it helps, but this is how we are doing something similar with this public key, in a Java application.  It takes the key file and builds an object that  has a fully-formed x509 certificate, which gets sent to Elastic along with the request...and it works.

```
File caFile = new File("elastic_key_file.crt");
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(caFile);
X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(null, null);
keystore.setCertificateEntry("public", cer);
```

**(edit)**

Ended up being not related to SSL or that certificate Elastic gave me...which ended up being a point of confusion for me as I thought it was important.  Here are the proxy settings in nginx that worked:

```
# Get the origin into a variable, for substitution into the header, below
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?incomingdomain.com(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    default "";
}

proxy_redirect off;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization';

location /ElasticSearch/someSearch {
    proxy_pass https://elasticdomain/_search;
}
```

Comment: I'd comment, but I don't have enough reputation. You can't. You'll need the private key.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, you cannot create certificate and private key from a certificate. This would be a huge security problem if this was possible since the certificate is considered public and the private key should be kept secret.

> ... but this is how we are doing something similar with this public key ...

The code you show has nothing to do with your requirement. It just loads a certificate from a file (`generateCertificate` does not create a certificate, it just creates a certificate *object* from existing data). No *private* key is created here.

> ```
>    proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/client.pem;
>    proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/client.key;
> ```

I think you are on the wrong path in the first place. While you don't provide any useful details about the certificate you got, I assume that this certificate is the certificate of the Elasticsearch endpoint and you should use it to **verify** that the certificate is the expected one. In this case you would need to use the option [proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate file](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate) and there is **no private key needed** for this.

What you instead try to do with `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` is to **authenticate yourself** against the server with the certificate, i.e. use it as a client certificate.

Comment: thanks.  So, maybe if I just generate a self-signed cert and use that along with the public key I got from Elastic as the ssl 'trusted certificate', it might work?

Comment: @CC: see updated answer. I think you just try to use the wrong options in the first place.

Comment: Steffen, thank you.  I will give that a shot.  I'm sorry I didn't provide further details but literally what I got from the ES endpoint was "here is your certificate".  I had to decode it to see that it is a public RSA keyed file.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing seems to work.  I can't get ES to accept the connection even with setting proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate  (and also adding my own signed key) to the nginx reverse proxy.  Looks like I will have to find another solution other than Elasticsearch...

Comment: Turns out I was on a completely wrong path, largely due to my lack of understanding about the purpose for the certificate Elasticsearch provides.  In the end, I got it to work and it was a very simply proxy_pass with nginx -- but with the added return headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers.  This 'tricks' the browser that made the request to the reverse proxy into allowing the pre-flight and POST to happen.  I didn't even need the certificate at all.